# Polymorphic Associations and signup forms Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, polymorphism

I have a User table in Rails and it has 2 user types. I associated them with polymorphic associations, my models are:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true

class Buyer < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :user, as: :owner, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

class Seller < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :user, as: :owner, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
```

I need a registration form in HTML for new users and automatically specify their type (each user type has their own registration link)

How do I manage the controllers and HTML form to do this? The user is going to fill the form with information for the User and Buyer or Seller model.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 routes, one for buyer and another for seller. And then you can use Rail's form helpers:

```
<%= form_for :buyer do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :user %>
    [your user fields here]
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The form is analogous for the seller.

Comment: Thank you! Do I need to change the controller methods? Or can leave like `def new
  @buyer = Buyer.new
end` ?

Comment: The new and edit should be fine like that. The create and update may have to be tweaked.